# Blocking illegal traffic to a vps using ufw or/and iptables

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, ufw

I am totally new in this, and I didn't know how to phrase my question title, so it might not be that accurate, forgive me on that matter beforehand.

I'm getting some strange requests in my apache access log every day on my vps, to just list a few here they are :

```
IPFROMCHINA - - [09/Jun/2015:11:59:03 +0430] "GET /v2/rating/dbank.hxb.com.cn HTTP/1.1" 404 1259 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
IPFROMCHINA - - [09/Jun/2015:11:59:14 +0430] "GET /v2/rating/dbank.hxb.com.cn HTTP/1.1" 404 1259 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
DIFFERENTIPFROMCHINA - - [09/Jun/2015:11:59:48 +0430] "GET /scjs/cjs/ctxjs.js?aff_id=1145&subaff_id=300266104830000000&sbrand=Lights%20Cinema%201.5beta HTTP/1.1" 404 1307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
ANOTHERDIFFERENTIPFROMCHINA - - [09/Jun/2015:11:59:52 +0430] "GET /scjs/cjs/ctxjs.js?aff_id=1145&subaff_id=300266104830000000&sbrand=Lights%20Cinema%201.5beta HTTP/1.1" 404 1306 "http://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220o.1000855.w8621558-9482008722.26.QRbIJn&id=45280033824" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
CHINAIP - - [09/Jun/2015:12:00:21 +0430] "GET /scjs/cjs/ctxjs.js?aff_id=1145&subaff_id=300266104830000000&sbrand=Lights%20Cinema%201.5beta HTTP/1.1" 404 1307 "http://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220o.1000855.1998025129.1.a5OfES&id=45186779124&abbucket=_AB-M32_B5&rn=&acm=03054.1003.1.244085&aldid=xgVYQGQO&abtest=_AB-LR32-PV32_1563&scm=1003.1.03054.13_45186779124_244085&pos=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
CHINAIP - - [09/Jun/2015:12:01:05 +0430] "GET /scjs/cjs/ctxjs.js?aff_id=1145&subaff_id=300266104830000000&sbrand=Lights%20Cinema%201.5beta HTTP/1.1" 404 1307 "http://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a220o.1000855.w8621558-9482008722.18.QRbIJn&id=44276612782" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

So I asked arround and realized that this a way getting into my vps, I dont know how! Anyway, I used iptables to block china range ip addresses and there were quite a lot of them too, but I still get the following in my log! There also some requests from Poland and US too! I also set up ufw to only allow traffic on the ports that my website's running and deny the rest!

Is there any way that I can completely block this kind of requests to this server? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your requirements. For example, you may have a private website that you need to access only by yourself and some other friends / partners, etc. In this case, you can only allow specific IPs and deny the rest.

However, in some other cases when you have a public website, you can't simply do that because you don't know who may visit your website. Other things may help in this is to specify upper limit for requests/second per IP.

The fundamental security rule is to allow as least as possible to lower the risks.

Comment: my website is public, so i cannot deny all except some! but i can rule out china easily. I did block a big range of ips from china, but im still getting requests from china, so do you know a trick to block requests completely from a country so that no more requests are allowed? because closing ip ranges is not working completely here!

Comment: @AshkanKzme: So, you may need to get a recent update of country-based IP database and excluded the countries you want.

Comment: but i think even that won't do the trick am i right? because there might still be a lot of ips left out!